# before insert trigger IF statement not working

Tags: mysql

I have created a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on some table in my mySQL database but somehow it is not working. If I strip the first IF statement everything works correctly, but with the IF statement in place the code is not executed. Is the field not yet filled in `NEW` or something? The field merchant exists and is filled with 'merchantName'.

```
IF(NEW.merchant = 'merchantName') THEN
    SET NEW.category = CASE 
         WHEN NEW.name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%cat1%' THEN 'Category1'
         ELSE 'Others'
    END;
END IF
```

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

I now have created the trigger from scratch including the CREATE TRIGGER sequence and included a changed Delimiter (as someone posted as comment, and removed later): Still not working :(

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `updateCategories` BEFORE INSERT ON `products`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF(NEW.merchant = 'merchantName') THEN
   SET NEW.category = CASE 
    WHEN NEW.name COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%cat1%' THEN 'Category1'
    ELSE 'Others'
   END;
  END IF;
 END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

FIXED:
After being pointed to run the insert command for the insert directly I found out this worked, and after that I concluded it had to be something with an INSERT being followed by an UPDATE. So I added another trigger which does the same thing only now being an BEFORE UPDATE trigger. This works perfectly!

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you post the query which is suppose to trigger it?

Comment: The query that triggers it, is set in a huge script where I cannot directly find the palce that does the actual INSERT.

Comment: Try running an insert manually trough a MySQL client.

Comment: @Vatev It works if I just insert it by hand with an INSERT INTO statement from the phpMyAdmin page. So to me this looks like the INSERT command is not correct for this trigger. Maybe the order in which the fields are filled is not correct or something? Or an INSERT is only done for the key fields after which an UPDATE is done for the rest? I will continue my search.

Comment: The exact syntax of the insert query doesn't matter. It is most likely an insert followed by an update. You should probably  create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger too anyway.

Comment: @Vatev That is exactly what I did and it fixed the problem! :) Thanks, for pointing me in the right direction!